# In predict.C5.0(modelFit, newdata, trial = submodels$trials[j]) :

Tags: r, r-caret, ensemble-learning

I am doing C5.0 modeling using Caret.
while doing it, I am faced with this problem.
here is my code.

```
control <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=5, repeats=2, classProbs=TRUE, summaryFunction=mnLogLoss) #should be Logloss

train1$GROUP<-as.factor(train1$GROUP)
train1$GROUP = make.names(train1$GROUP)

xgb_model3 <- caret::train(GROUP ~ .,data = subset(train1, select=-ID), method = "C5.0",metric = "logLoss",trControl = control)
```

My data, train1, consists of GROUP of 6 classes(=multiclass) and ID, HOUR....( all numeric)

```
str(train1) : Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame
```

The problem is following error.

> Warning messages: 1: In predict.C5.0(modelFit, newdata, trial =
>   submodels$trials[j]) :   'trials' should be <= 7 for this object.
>   Predictions generated using 7 trials

How can I solve this problem? Please give me some solutions.

Comment: That is a warning not an error, It usually works like that, try running `summary(xgb_model3)` and `print(xgb_model3)` , they should give you right outcomes.